# How do I compare the variable of the current dataset to the same variable of the preceding-sibling?

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I am currently using Inline XSLT Call Template inside of Biztalk to create a mapping from a flat .csv file to an xml document. The flat file is read in one line at a time and operated on. In my flat file, we have a string (RecordID) that indicates the record of the item. Many rows may have the same record, but each item is unique to that record. In the case that 2 items have the same record, I only wish to map it once. What I am trying to do is compare the value the RecordID from the current line to the RecordID of the preceding-sibling. This is what my code looks like in the attempt to do this:

```
<xsl:param name="RecordID" />
<xsl:for-each select="$RecordID">
<xsl:if test="$RecordID != preceding-sibling::$RecordID">
// Do stuff here
```

What's the proper way to access variables from the preceding-sibling?

Comment: you may want to consider grouping

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf442751-c525-4822-b625-0b97dfd04a03/how-to-map-only-unique-values-in-biztalk-mapper?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more context here. For example, what does your input XML look like, and what output do you expect? Also, what is `RecordID` exactly set to? If it is literally a string, then it doesn't make sense to for `xsl:for-each` on it. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "The flat file is read in one line at a time and operated on"? You can't compare two records if they're debatched into separate XML files.